# conversion from int to DATE is unsupported on null date

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I believe this has been a bug/problem in SQL 2000/2005 ... If my results have null on DATETIME column, i get

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception: 
 the conversion from int to date is unsupported
```

when i use `sql.getDate("ColumnName")` ... 
Any solutions to this?

[EDIT]
Hi all thanks for your inputs, below is my SQL query

```
select p.planno            as PlanNumber, 
       t.TrancheID         as TrancheID, 
       t.tranchestartdate  as TrancheStartDate, 
       t.tranchereasoncode as TrancheReasonCode, 
       ai.ArrayItemDecode  TrancheReasonDescription, 
       t.trancheuwstage    as UnderwritingStatusCode 
from   plan_ p 
       inner join tranche t 
         on t.planno = p.planno 
            and t.trancheuwstage in ( 2, 4 ) 
            and p.planno = '040000000X6' 
       inner join arrayitem ai 
         on ai.ArrayNm = 'arrTraReas' 
            and ai.ArrayItemCode = t.tranchereasoncode;
```

and the culprit here is tranchestartdate which is a DATETIME. I can't really add anything to tabel as i'm not allowed to change existing table structures, this is a big system. Perhaps i can do the casting in my SQL? I'm not quite sure if this is definitely a null problem.. Can one debug/watch through the ResultSet and check if any data was retrieved before i call getDate()? 
[/EIDT]

Comment: Don't have `null` dates?

Comment: There must be a reason JDBC thinks the column is int. Are you sure the SQL field is not of TIMESTAMP data type?

Comment: @James. A `NULL` literal without any casting is treated as `int` by SQL Server but `int` does cast to `datetime` OK. `SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` gives `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` and `SELECT CAST(CAST(NULL AS INT) AS DATETIME)` gives `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application (or drivers) cannot handle null dates then the easiest thing might be to use ISNULL(field, <null replacement date>) and check for the null replacement date in code. This approach uses a magic number (date) to indicate null values, true. It's not pretty but it is quick and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use coalesce for this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you selecting the datetime from a field or constructing it dynamically in your `SELECT`? you may have to `CAST` the result.

See [this article](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/287859/1-1-jdbc-driver-gettimestamp-on-null-value-throws-sqlexception)